# Unable to write to the stream using the reference stored in express-session

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, express-session

In my project, I am uploading a huge file of few GBs to the server, in chunks - 10MB chunk at a time, using the [blueimp jQuery-File-Upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).

I have a `writeStream` at the Node.js backend attached to a [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session), just so the file uploads from 2 different users do not get messed up. I create a `writeStream` for every upload and attach it to the session.

*The problem is that*, when the first data chunk is received at the backend, the `writeStream.write` is not found in the session.

**Relevant part of my Node.js / Express.js code:**

```
// session config:
expressApp.use(session({
    genid: function(req) {
        return uuidV1();
    },
    secret: '***',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false }
}));

// create writeStream
expressApp.post('/createStream', function(request, response) {

    request.session.wstream = fileSystem.createWriteStream(uploadsDirectoryLocation + '/' + request.body.fileName);

    request.session.wstream.on('finish', function() {
        console.log('*********************************** file has been written ***********************************');
    });

    response.send({ response: 'success' });

});


// on every chunk received, write to the stream
expressApp.post('/uploadFile', function(request, response) {

    var size = 0;

    console.log(request.session.wstream);  // the attached 'wstream' does show up

    request.on('data', function(data) {
        size += data.length;

        request.session.wstream.write(data);  // app crashes here

        console.log('Got chunk: ' + data.length + ' total: ' + size);
        console.log('data', data);
    });

    request.on('end', function() {
        console.log("total size = " + size);
        response.send("response");
    });

    request.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
        response.send("response");
    });

});

// close the stream
expressApp.post('/closeStream', function(request, response) {

    request.session.wstream.end();

    response.send({ response: 'success' });

});
```

The exact error is:

```
        streamObj.wstream.write(data);
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

***However***, If am not attaching the `writeStream` to the session and keeping it global, it does work. But, not for different sessions.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I head back from one of the `express-session` repo maintainers on GitHub:](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/433#issuecomment-282420037)

> The reason is that the data in `req.session` is saved to the database using `JSON.stringify`, and functions cannot be represented in there. You can only store simple values like numbers and strings in `req.session`, not complex functions, unfortunately.

I resolved the issue by eliminating `writeStream` completely and using `openSync` to create an empty file and `appendFileSync` to append data to the file on every chunk received.